# ajax function not reading success/error call

Tags: jquery, ajax

Whenever i call success or error in my ajax nothing seems to run, however if i change it to complete it works fine. Here is the simplest example from my program i can show:

html:

```
<label>Test Server:</label>
<button id="btnTest">Test</button>
```

.js:

```
$('#btnTest').click(function() {
test();
}); 

function test() {
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: rootURL + '/'+'testing',
    dataType: "text",
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
       $('#message').html(data.responseText);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus+":"+errorThrown);
        $('#message').html("No Response");
    }
});
}
```

However if i change to to use a complete function instead like below it works fine.

```
complete: function (data, status) {
        $('#message').html(data.responseText);
}
```

Is there an obvious error i am missing here?

Edit: Here is the relevent code fromt he server and i've also added the code that calls the js function to the above code block.

```
@GET
@Produces("text/plain")
@Path("/testing")
public String testing() {
    return "Test passed.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error. You need to concat the error vars within you alert and a missing parentheses at the end.

```
alert(textStatus+":"+errorThrown);
```

Without seeing the whole thing - you can only return the values from a synchronous function. Otherwise you will have to make a callback. Add `async:false,`

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: rootURL + '/'+'testing',
    dataType: "text",
    async:false,
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
       $('#message').html(data.responseText);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus+":"+errorThrown
        $('#message').html("No Response");
    }
});
```

Comment: Synchronous AJAX is the weirdest thing that I've ever seen in Javascript. But it's possible.Why not? However, I think this doesn't solve the user's problem. I don't know why his ajax function doesn't reach `success` or `error` callback, if it's managed by jQuery

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude his code should work - becasue what ever is causing the issue isn't within the code displayed within the question i'm suggesting a fix that I've previously encountered. Personally i'd need to see the whole script in order to provide a more complete answer.

Comment: Me too. I agree with you :)

Comment: the syntax error must have happened when i was formatting the code in the post a question box, i've edited that now, i will test the `async:false` part now, what else can i add there to show? the only other part of the script is adding a click event to a button that just calls this function

Comment: I have added `async:false` to the ajax but it still has the same problem as before, I'm not entirely sure what I'm missing here, i can post any of the source here that would be useful, i've already added more to the OP

Comment: I'd run it through something like `firebug` at this point. Have you got a link to a test page? I'd also try hitting a php script that simply has `print('hello world');`.

Comment: Just ran it through firebug and in the console it shows that it got a response from the `GET` request, so for some reason the success isn't getting called back is my guess?

Comment: How do you know it isn't getting called? Put console.log(data) in the success function.

Comment: Ok i just assumed it wasn't as `#message` wasn't getting changed, this shows in the log now so the error must be somewhere else.

Comment: You can use the log to correctly target the variable you need to populate the text element. I'd suggest using a json encoded array within your php script

Comment: I changed the line `$('#message').html(data.responseText);` to `$('#message').html(data);` and it seems to work just fine? when outputting `data.responseText` is seemed to be undefined

Comment: Data will be everything that's returned from the php script.

Comment: It's from a java ReST server not php, all its returning is a single String

Comment: The same principle applies.